Wire came loose from disconnect box not sure where it goes
[![enter image description here[mini split label[I have 2 mini splits connected to the same disconnect box. I no longer use 1 of the mini splits even though it is still connected. A black wire coming from the new mini split i am using is no longer connected and i would like to connect it again so i can use the ac. Where did the wire fall out of? Or can i just unscrew the black wire from the mini split i will not be using and connect this loose black wire in its place?

Please add more info to the question.  Is the box in the photo floating free in your hand?  How and to what is it normally connected?  Where do the two wires entering from the rear hole go?  Did that hole have a connector before you unmounted the box? I'm looking for a ground path back to the breaker box.  Is the left compressor a 120V one?  Is the red wire stub not connected at the other end?  Can you add photos of the electrical rating plate for the left A/C?  Is the right one being permanently decommissioned?

Why is the neutral grounded in this box?

The box is usually mounted to the mini split by a screw. The hole in the back has a black and red wire that is connected to the mini split behind the box. Ill have to respond to the other questions tomorrow as the ac is on tbe roof and its dark out now.

So the conduit on the right with the green wire goes to the breaker?  And the disconnect is mounted on the unit being decommissioned?

The disconnect box is mounted to the old compressor that we no longer are using. The old compressor is connected to the disconnect box through a hole in the back with a red and black wire. The new compressor is connected to the disconnect box from the bottom left hand side and it has a black white and tiny brown wire. The bottom right side has a green black and red wire and that is connected to the breaker box.
